# Ubuntu Server 11.10 from USB?

Tags: server

I tried 'burning' the .iso onto a USB like I normally would with Ubuntu Desktop or Server 12.04, but it gives me an error during installation and tells me that it can't get files from CD or something.  So, is a USB installation of Server 11.10 not possible?

P.S. I need to install 11.10 because 12.04 is giving me a LOT of problems trying to convert to a static IP.

Comment: What do you use to create the USB boot drive ? UNetBootin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally installed various Ubuntu server versions from USB. I use the Ubuntu Startup Disc Creator (installed by default in Ubuntu desktop editions). I do remember something like this happening to me with another distro, and I think it had to do with the way I made the USB stick. This http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1369628 thread suggests that unetbootin could be the source of the issue in at least one instance, which also confirms my experience. If you haven't already, I'd try the Ubuntu Startup Disc Creator.

I have assumed you have an Ubuntu desktop install, my apologies if not.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

To install the desktop version of Ubuntu via USB drive, I used this tool: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Certainly it won't be much different with the server version.